# Simple XML parsing using jquery?

Tags: jquery, xml, parsing, cross-domain

Sorry if this is similar to my other question, but I've been researching and I think I can phrase it better.  I'm trying to parse the XML file found at http://xproshowcasex.channel-api.livestream-api.com/2.0/getstream
All I am worried about is the isLive element. How can I make the isLive status an object so if it is true I can do one thing, and if it is false do another. The code below is pretty basic, but it's all I've got.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET"
    url: getstreamurl,
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml) {
    }
});
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: isn't this a violation of the cross-domain ajax request policy?  http://usejquery.com/posts/9/the-jquery-cross-domain-ajax-guide

Comment: @Stefan I'm using a plugin that uses yql. Can you request an XML document using jsonp?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like it might not work because of the [cross-domain request policy](http://usejquery.com/posts/9/the-jquery-cross-domain-ajax-guide) but here's a tutorial on XML parsing with jQuery: [Parse XML with jQuery](http://papermashup.com/parse-xml-with-jquery/)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using YQL  you can try out:
http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/cross-domain-requests-with-jquery/

The cross domain AJAX outputs JSONP via YQL which you can then import into your site. This will circumvent any cross-domain issues.

Comment: +1 for using YQL to get around crossdomain policy. I've use PHP+CURL and YQL both (when I don't control the xml). Nice mention.